# WordPress plugin/theme suggestion

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am looking for a WordPress plugin/theme that offers similar functionality to this website: https://secure.heathrow.com

The search would essentially be the same, leading through to a few options which you can then book/purchase via a payment merchant.

I have ploughed through wordpress.org plugins section, and had no joy.

If anyone can recommend or know of anything similar, as has any type of solution I would be most grateful! :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not find a specific WordPress plugin tailored to that type of search and purchase function.  If you look at the source code for that site (in Chrome, View -> Developer -> View Source), you will see that the main script that is running the search is an .asp script (Microsoft product).  This is likely a custom built site.

There are some plugins that will help you with e-commerce on the WordPress platform such as WooCommerce, Shopify, WP Ecommerce, etc, all of which do charge fees for the services provided in the plugin.  Many people who run e-commerce sites often find developers to work with them to build something more custom than these platform plugins can provide.

Instead, look for a search function plugin in WordPress to go through your database, then evaluate the e-commerce platform plugins for a functional match. A good rule of thumb in WordPress is that if you can't find an exact plugin for what you want, try to break the pieces down into components and search for a plugin for each of the components.